# URLForResource returns nil

Tags: xcode

I'm in the process of learning how to use xcode and how to write applications for the Mac.

So, I have a simple screensaver that loads an external file which works fine. I decided that it would be better to embed the html source in the application to reduce the external dependancies.

I dragged the HTML file to the resources folder, it's at the top level there's no sub folder or anything.

[image: resource added]

I made sure the Add to targets had my application in it, along with selecting 'create folder references' and 'copy files if needed'. I use the following to get the url to the file, but it returns nil

```
    NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"embedded" withExtension:@"html"];


 System Preferences[10185]: fileUrl returned (null)
```

I've read through all the other SO issues for the similar problems but none of the fixes seem to apply. I've gone through and checked them.

If I show the package contents of the final build the embedded.html is in there. Am I missing something really obvious?

**edit to add**

In build phases it's listed in Copy Bundle Resources

[image]

xcode version is 6.1.1

Comment: Have you checked that in your build phases the file is under `Copy Bundle Resources`?

Comment: Yes, it's there to be copied. I've just added the image to the question.

Comment: Is this a command line tool? If so it doesn't have an App Bundle. You need to make a Cocoa application instead.

Comment: No, not a command line tool, it's a screen saver

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some considerable digging and a smidgeon of luck I found that

```
    NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"embedded" withExtension:@"html"];
```

is incorrect and I should be using

```
    NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"embedded" withExtension:@"html"];
```

instead.

i.e.  **NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]** and not NSBundle mainBundle will give access to a screensaver bundle.

Might be obvious, but only if you know ;)

See [Apple Developer NSBundle Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleForClass:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Definitely wasn't expecting this. A bit strange that something that has been working since the very beginning changes all of a sudden.

Comment: Wow, after 5 zillion searches, 3 head-to-keyboards, 4 smoke breaks, 2 naps to 'sleep on it", and 6 jelly donuts, I finally found this solution. Hmmm, you would think -- with half the worlds liquidity, Apple would write some decent, unified, centralized, non-fragmented, precise, non TL;DR, for-crying-out-loud documentation. (where's that mac power button again?)

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. The answer for me was to check the Target Membership of object's identity. [image: target membership must be selected for any object to be analyzed or accessed in the app]

Answer (score 0):

Quitting and restarting Xcode fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

using this solved my problem `[myBundle URLForResource: withExtension: subdirectory: ]`

Subdirectory queries to NSBundle URLForResource need to specify the subdirectory. Otherwise it returns nil.

One hour figuring this today :'(

Answer (score 0):

I met a same issue in a MAC application. After several hours, I found an easy way to fix it.

1, Make sure there is a phase named "Copy Files" under "Build Phases". If not, please add one.

2, Add your resources into the phase.
[image]

3, Rebuild your project and you can find your resources located in **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug/**.