# How can I properly load an HTML file into a UIWebView without it crashing over a nil value? (Swift)

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to perform the simple task of loading an all-text html file into a UIWebView in Swift. I have created a simple test html file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE: html>

<html>

<body>
test
</body>
```

Seems simple enough to me. I have it within the project files, so I think it's in the right place.

Here is my basic swift code, where I am trying to load the html file.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "html")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

I've seen examples like this all over this website and many others, but nobody seems to have the same problem I am having. 
It crashes on this line:

```
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!)
```

The error message says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it (in Swift)? Am I missing something? Is the html file in the wrong place? The problem seems to be with the html file, not the webview, as I was previously able to load the blank webview by itself before I wrote this code.

Comment: That might help you to solve getting nil when getting your content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999081/urlforresource-returns-nil

Comment: I'm looking into bundles now, but it seems that the solution that this guy found is written wildly different in Swift.

Comment: You can easily convert it to Swift. By the way on another note, your test.html contains html, but in your code, you are dealing with the html content as a URL. Mistake?

Comment: This project that I'm working on has been one new concept to learn after another. I followed a few tutorials that lead me to believe this is the right way to call the file. Am I calling my file incorrectly then?

Comment: I can help you out when I go back home because I am not in front of my Mac right now. Will repro and let you know what I find :)

Comment: I would appreciate it! It may also be my project - it's pretty large (creating an app that will be released in April for a software engineering class - quite the learning curve sometimes). I often run into troubles because of other people's code and get weird errors.

Comment: Your code works for me. Since you're getting URL=nil, it's telling you it can't find "test.html". Could yours be in a subfolder?

Comment: Well that's just fantastic...I really don't know why this is happening. I looked in the "copy bundle resources" and it's there. My webview is able to load a website with a url, but can't do anything with my html file.

Comment: You'll never believe what I totally forgot to do. I didn't name my file test.html, I just named it test. *mega facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

The code that I posted was actually correct. I had stupidly forgotten to name the file 'test.html', and instead just named it 'test'. It's the dumb little things that can hang you up for hours! Don't make my mistake.

Comment: why not go ahead and mark your own answer as correct?  (helps your 'points' on SO - another one of those 'little things', but you may find it useful in the future)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got this error was because the `NSURL` that got returned from `NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "html")` was nil, then your force unwrapped that value. Try wrapping that in an `if let` statement:

```
if let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "html") {
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

Also I would figure out why your test.html. It must not be in your apps bundle